# Python file management does not always work?

Tags: python, filesystems

I encounter a strange problem. I have a BBB with Debian 2015-11-03. My python 2.7 application runs automatically at start up. I do some file management in my script. In this case that part of the script does not work. No error messages visible. Just nothing. When I start my application manually in LX terminal (sudo python aceme.py, same command line as in auto mode, same dir) that part of the script works perfect.

Part of script under debate:

```
def correction():                                   # to implement the antenna 
                                                       # correction values 
    if abs(az_delta)<5 and abs(el_delta)<5:
        azimc = az_delta
        elevc = el_delta
        conf_data = ""                               # if we accept the 
                          # corrections we need to save them for future use 
        input_file = open('acemedat.py', 'r')
        for line in input_file:
        if 'azcor =' in line:
            line = 'azcor = ' + str(azimc) + '\r\n'
        if 'elcor =' in line:
            line = 'elcor = ' + str(elevc) + '\r\n'
        conf_data += line 
        input_file.close()
        output_file = open ('acemedat.py', 'w')
        output_file.write(conf_data)
        output_file.close()  
        az_cor.configure(text = str('%5.1f' % azimc))
        el_cor.configure(text = str('%5.1f' % elevc))
        message.configure(text="Correction values acknowledged and saved")
    else:
        message.configure(text="Correction denied: delta > 5 degrees")
    clear_message.configure(state='normal')
    return;
```

In all cases the else clause works as expected.
What do I need to do to rectify this situation?
Thanks in advance,
Harke

Comment: Is the working directory at startup, where the scripts runs (and looks for the acmedat.py), the same as when you execute it manually?

Comment: Hmmm, I am terribly sorry to have bothered you: the classical directory issue. It's clearly solved now. Thanks a lot! Harke

Comment: :) np. I made it an answer so you can mark it as solved. This way the question gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

Is the working directory at startup, where the scripts runs (and looks for the acmedat.py), the same as when you execute it manually?

Comment: @harke-smits Please mark the answer as solution if it was (which I think is the case, see comments above).